# testing string for NULL value while loop not working

Tags: c, string, while-loop

EDIT: sorry, it's in C not C++, I get them mixed up sometimes. I changed `lengthN == NULL` to `lengthN == 0` and I'm getting an infinite loop after I enter the first name (if the name is longer than 15 characters).

So I am trying to make this thing that enters player names for this game I have to make for an assignment, and for some reason it doesn't repeatedly go through the loop. The loop SHOULD check the string length and if it is set to `NULL` which would be outside the buffer, it will ask the user to re input, and will repeat itself until the correct length is input.

```
printf_s("Enter player %d's name (Max 15 characters): ", count);
scanf_s("%s", &name, 15);
lengthN = strlen(name);
printf_s("\n%s\n%d", name,lengthN);

while (lengthN == NULL)
{
    printf_s("\nName too big; please enter a name within 15 
    characters!\n\n");
    scanf_s("Enter name: %s", &name, 15);
    lengthN = strlen(name);
}
```

Comment: May want to pick a language. This looks like C. In C++, there's a true `std::string` class which can't be NULL.

Comment: Are you in C or C++ ? Please, don't use both tag, say clearly which language you're using.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code in a debugger, while observing the values of the variables (e.g. `lengthN`)?

Comment: By the way, neither in C nor in C++ it makes sense to compare the result of `strlen`, an integer, to `NULL`, which is value for pointers.

Comment: Did you do memset 0 to the name? May be it contains the previous entry still

Comment: Could you also give an example of a result you are getting with your code while testing?

Comment: Just to be sure: please show the definitions of `name`.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `while` loop at all, because `scanf` with the %s format specifier won't even let you enter an empty string. It won't let you enter spaces either. If you want spaces to be entered [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf). But `scanf` is complicated and sometimes weird, I suggest you rather use `fgets`.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare string *length* (which is in an *integer* value) to `NULL` (which is intended for *pointer* contexts)?

Comment: name is `char name[16]`

Comment: Try `for(;;){ int retVal = scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name)); if(retVal == -1) { puts("EOF"); } else if(retVal == 0) { fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n"); scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar(); } else { break; } }`

Answer (score 0):

lengthN won't be equal to NULL (at least in C), as [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) return you a `size_t` element which is a numeric value. At least to make your code more logical, you should instead test in your while loop if lengthN is equal to 0, and then ask the user to enter a name until the length is different to 0.

```
while (lengthN == 0)
{
    printf_s("\nName too big; please enter a name within 15 
    characters!\n\n");
    scanf_s("Enter name: %s", &name, 15);
    lengthN = strlen(name);
}
```

Comment: It depends if C or C++. As in C++ NULL is just an old plain 0, it can work, even if it makes to sense.

Comment: `NULL`, typically (at least from what I saw), is just a `#define NULL 0`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius in C++, but not in C

Comment: @manni66 That's why I said in the way, that I did.. _Typically_ **does not** mean _always_, and _from what I saw_, means, well.. Anywhere that I developed it was defined like that. I **didn't state** it was _always_ defined in this way.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`scanf_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)'s documentation:

> Returns the number of fields successfully converted and assigned; the return value does not include fields that were read but not assigned. A return value of 0 indicates that no fields were assigned.  The return value is EOF for an error, or if the end-of-file character or the end-of-string character is encountered in the first attempt to read a character.

Shouldn't you check instead against the value returned by `scanf_s()` in the condition for the `while` loop?

```
while (scanf_s("%s", &name, 15))
   ;
```

Comment: I thought I was?
`lengthN = strlen(name)` which is getting the characters of name as an int then comparing?

Comment: That didn't work either. The loop is either going into an infinite loop or only iterates once, and the code you've posted only loops if the characters are within 15, which is the opposite of what it's supposed to do.

Comment: try removing the check against EOF

Comment: So what it should do is: First ask the user to enter a name less than or equal to 15 characters, then check if the name is within those parameters, if not, it should loop and ask again until the user has put in the correct data.

Comment: @Robert, after calling `scanf_s()` check the return value, it's the size of the bytes written to `name` . But be also aware of getting EOF as the return value of `scanf_s()`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf_s("%s", &name, 15);` is not expected to fill `name` with a zero length *string*.  [@Michael Walz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064902/testing-string-for-null-value-while-loop-not-working/44067043#comment75154994_44064902)

It consumes leading white-space until some non-white-space is entered - which is saved in `name`.  (end-of-file and rare input error are exceptions).

`lengthN = strlen(name);` is thus non-zero.

... and `while (lengthN == NULL)` is always false.

Comment: So what test should I do instead?

Comment: @robert Coding goal lacks details for "what test should I do instead": What types are used, sizeof  arrays, sample input like are  "Betty Jo", "1234", " valid for a first name?  Without details, like these, "what test should I do instead" could be an iterative  process for a best answer.