# C Switch default case not triggering

Tags: c, pointers, switch-statement

I'm stuck at a pretty awkward thing. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void processCommand(){
    char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);

    scanf("%s", c);

    switch(*c){
    case '!': 
        printf("Action");
        break;
    case '?': 
        printf("Question");
        break;
    default: 
        printf("Unknown Action");
        break;
    }
}
```

So what I want is, if the first char of my input is something different than `!` or `?`, it should just say it's an unknown action. So it works for typing other characters, but everytime i type a whitespace / tab / nothing, it doesn't do anything ?

Comment: Are you complaining about flushing?

Comment: You mean entering some whitespace, then pressing enter? Well, scanf will skip whitespace, so you read nothing in and stay within scanf until you enter some non-whitespace...

Comment: It's working fine in GCC compiler on Linux platform.

Comment: Just a side note: You don't really need `malloc` here, you can simply have: `char c[128];` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users pointed out: [scanf ignores whitespaces, fgets doesn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

```
void processCommand(){
    char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    fgets (c, sizeof(char) * 128, stdin);

    switch(*c){
        case '!': 
            printf("Action");
            break;
        case '?': 
            printf("Question");
            break;
        default: 
            printf("Unknown Action");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Dont answer a duplicate question

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu You may be right :)

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu You're right though, I shouldn't have answered it, I'll be more cautious next time and stick to the flag/comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: @underscore_d see easy 25 reputation :/