# Get a string and extract 2 substring in c

Tags: c, string, substring

I just want to read from input a string of the form "c4 d5" and save two substring :

str1 = "c4"

str2 = "d5"

I tried:

```
char action[5];
char str1[2];
char str2[2];
scanf("%s", action);
strncpy(str1, &action[0], 2);
strncpy(str2, &action[3], 2);
```

but it gives me strange behaviors....

Also as I am learning c, I'm looking for both solutions using only char * and only char[] (either in input and output).

Comment: Dont use strncpy() until you know what it does.

Comment: Please always add the output you get.

Comment: `scanf` will stop reading at the space character. So `action` contains "c4".

Comment: The output is kind of weird and it depends on other factors in my code, for the first time is something like :
input: ciaoo
output: ci
ooci

Comment: `strncpy` will *not* add a terminating 0 to your strings. And your target strings also cannot hold more than a single character (*plus* one position for aforementioned terminating 0). It doesn't add up well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you expire strange behaviour ALWAYS read the man pages of the functions you are using. A C string should with almost no exceptions end with a \0 because otherwise printf/puts will probably not only print what you want but also some random memory fragments. Also the index starts at 0 so in order to get the third char you need to use [2].

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char action[5];
    char str1[3];
    char str2[3];

    scanf("%s", action);

    strncpy(str1, action, 2);
    strncpy(str2, &action[2], 2);

    str1[2] = '\0';
    str2[2] = '\0';

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);

    return 0;
}
```

[Try it out](https://onlinegdb.com/HkmPTZVcG)

[man page of strncpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)

> The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied. Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Comment: I still have problems with the " " character, is it related with scanf?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: try to use the string "d4 e3" for the test, only d4 will be saved

Comment: I suggest you to look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Answer (score 0):

Here is a substring function. Don't forget to free the result when needed.

```
/**
 * Substrings in a new string, handles \0
 * @param char* str , the string to substring
 * @param int from , the start index included
 * @param int count , the amount of characters kept
 */
char * strsubstr(char * str , int from, int count) {
    char * result;

    if(str == NULL) return NULL;

    result = malloc((count+1) * sizeof(char));

    if(result == NULL) return NULL;

    strncpy(result, str+from, count);
    result[count] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you must understand some basic principles of c.
Scanf stops its `%s` "string-reader" if it's read a space 
secondly you can read both of the strings in once. "%s %s"
at this case you do not need the action variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char str1[2];
    char str2[2];
    scanf("%s %s",str1,str2);
    return 0;
}
```

This way you take cover of the space termination and the pointers game..

Comment: thanks, it's a cool solution but i still have to save the string for other purposes