# getting string with spaces from input in a switch case or loop

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, fgets

I try this code which I found on this website ([how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf))

```
           char name[15];         //or char*name=malloc(15);
           /* Ask user for name. */

            printf("What is your name? ");

            /* Get the name, with size limit. */

            fgets(name, MAX, stdin);

            /* Remove trailing newline, if there. */

            if ((strlen(name) > 0) && (name[strlen(name) - 1] == '\n'))
                name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';

            /* Say hello. */

            printf("Hello %s. Nice to meet you.\n", name);
```

When I run this code in main it works pretty well. Output is:

```
 What is your name? j k rowling
Hello j k rowling. Nice to meet you.
```

But when I put this code in a while loop or in a switch case:

```
        char name[15];
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
            printf("What is your name? ");

            /* Get the name, with size limit. */

            fgets(name, MAX, stdin);

            /* Remove trailing newline, if there. */

            if ((strlen(name) > 0) && (name[strlen(name) - 1] == '\n'))
                name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';

            /* Say hello. */

            printf("Hello %s. Nice to meet you.\n", name);


            break;  }
```

The output is:

```
What is your name? Hello . Nice to meet you.
```

So, it doesn't wait to entering a string. maybe fgets doesn't work I don't know.

How can I make this code work? Or any alternative to get string from input with all spaces. I tried this either:

```
switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("What is your name? ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
            printf("%s\n", name);  }
```

output is:

```
What is your name? ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
```

What is wrong with these? I use visiual studio. And I always get a trouble. Is this about it?

Comment: What do you mean "get string from input with all spaces"? Can you give an example?

Comment: I think you need to show a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Usually, this kind of problem occurs because some other input function left a newline character on the input.

Comment: What's your value for `MAX'?

Comment: @J...S MAX is 15. If I use scanf I get just  "abc" from "abc def". So I used fgets to have all chars with space. But it works only in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `stdin` is not getting *flushed* properly.

You need to manually *flush* it. (*fflush()* function is available. But it is *problematic*.)

Following is an example code to solve your issue. See it [working here](https://ideone.com/rBBSqM):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 15

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char name[MAX];
    char c;
    int choice=1;
    while(choice>0 && choice<3)
    {
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:

                //Flush stdin
                while ((c = getchar()) == '\n');
                ungetc(c, stdin);

                printf("What is your name? ");
                fgets(name, MAX, stdin);
                if ((strlen(name) > 0) && (name[strlen(name) - 1] == '\n'))
                name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';
                printf("Hello %s. Nice to meet you.\n", name);
            break;

            case 2:
                printf("Your choice is case 2\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```