# reading space character into string with size determined by str_size

Tags: c

I'm trying to make this program such that the user could type any given string of characters, and the program would separate alphanumerical characters from the rest, print them into a second string, and finally print the final result into the screen.

I've already tried using `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string);`, but it doesn't seem to work since the size of the string is not specified beforehand, and is rather defined by `STR_SIZE`.

```
char string[STR_SIZE];

printf("please type in a string \n");
scanf("%s", string);
printf("string: \n %s \n", string);
int size = (strlen(string));
char alfanumerico[STR_SIZE];
int count = 0;
int count2 = 0;

while(count <= size)
{
    if(string[count] >= '0' && string[count] <= '9')
    {
        alfanumerico[count2] = string[count];
        count2++;
    }
    if(string[count] >= 'a' && string[count] <= 'z')
    {
        alfanumerico[count2] = string[count];
        count2++;
    }
    if(string[count] >= 'A' && string[count] <= 'Z')
    {
        alfanumerico[count2] = string[count];
        count2++;
    }
    if(string[count] ==' ')
    {
        alfanumerico[count2] = string[count];
        count2++;
    }
    count++;
}

printf("alphanumerical characters typed: \n %s \n", alfanumerico);
```

Given the user typed a string such as: ```` -=-=[[][][]}}Hello 123 ```//././. ````

I expect the output to be: `Hello 123`

Comment: what? `%s` is even less right than `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string);`

Comment: Also your code formatting is horrible, hence it is hard to se if it is right or not, and you're not null-terminating the resulting string correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` is not the way to go, especially if your input might contain white-spaces on which `scanf` would stop reading more inputs and wouldn't store spaces for instance.

You should use `fgets` which lets you limit the input data according to the buffer this data is stored in. So something like:

```
fgets(string, STR_SIZE, stdin)
```

should work.

About the size - you should have some limitation about the maximum size of the string and then STR_SIZE should be set to this number. It should be part of your program requirements or just a size that makes sense if you're making the requirements. It must be defined before you're reading input from the user because the buffer memory is allocated **before** reading to it.

---

A comment about style, unrelated to your question - always try to decrease code duplication to 0. The line `alfanumerico[count2] = string[count]; count2++;` appears 4 times in your code. A more elegant minimal `if` statement with exactly the same functionality would be:

```
if ((string[count] >= '0' && string[count] <= '9') ||
    (string[count] >= 'a' && string[count] <= 'z') ||
    (string[count] >= 'A' && string[count] <= 'Z') || 
    (string[count] == ' '))
{
    alfanumerico[count2] = string[count];
    count2++;
}
```

and to be even more minimal:

```
char c = string[count];
if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
    (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ||
    (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || 
    (c == ' '))
{
    alfanumerico[count2] = c;
    count2++;
}
```

It's also more readable and more maintainable - if you want to change the variable `count` to `i` you do it in one place instead of 8.

Also, always close a scope in a new line.

Comment: I’m just getting started at my computer science, so all of this is kind of new for me.... . But thanks to people like you I can move forwards even when reaching a problem for which I’m not yet prepared to solve. Anyway, thanks for answering my question and also for the tips on how making my code less complicated, truly helpful 