# There is a proble in my code, Its not taking full string with spaces

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fighter
{
    char *name, *category;
    int weight, age;
};

void enter_data(struct fighter *f, int n);
void display(struct fighter *f, int n);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    struct fighter *f;

    printf("Enter no. of fighter: "); scanf("%d",&n);

    f = (struct fighter *)malloc(n*sizeof(struct fighter));

    enter_data(f, n);
    display(f, n);
    return 0;


    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        free((f+i)->name);
        free((f+i)->category);
    }
    free(f);
}

void enter_data(struct fighter *f, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){

        (f+i)->name=(char *)malloc(40*sizeof(char));
        (f+i)->category=(char *)malloc(40*sizeof(char));

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter name of fighter: "); 
        scanf("%s[^\n]",(f+i)->name);
        //its not working full name, when I'm trying to give full name with space (ie. John Trump) its not working but when I'm giving only first name (ie. John) its working fine...

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter age of fighter: ");  
        scanf("%d",&((f+i)->age));
        printf("Enter weight of fighter: ");  
        scanf("%d",&(f+i)->weight);
        printf("Enter category of fighter: "); 
        scanf("%s[^\n]",(f+i)->category);
    }
}

void display(struct fighter *f, int n){

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\n\n");
        printf(" Name of fighter: "); 
        puts((f+i)->name);
        printf(" Age of fighter: ");  
        printf("%d \n",(f+i)->age);
        printf(" Weight of fighter: ");   
        printf("%d \n",(f+i)->weight);
        printf(" Category of fighter: "); 
        puts((f+i)->category);
    }
}
```

See in **enter_data()** function in there I have commented my issue...

> When I'm giving full name with spaces its not taking rest of the
> inputs and directly jump to next iteration of loop.  But when I'm
> giving first name or name with no spaces then its working fine.

[This imgae is a output sceenshot when I'm giving full name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrCqz.png)

[This imgae is a output sceenshot when I'm giving first name only or name with no space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiwZ0.png)

Comment: `"%s[^\n]"` You probably want `"%[^\n]"` instead.

Comment: I would encourage you to consider [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).  Nevertheless, if you're going to use scanf() ... and if you expected embedded strings ... then your syntax is incorrect.  Here's one alternative: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str)`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-string-input-space-c-3-different-methods

Answer (score 0):

See [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Also, your `return 0` should be *after* loops for freeing resources.

Comment: You're correct .. but you probably should have voted "close/duplicate" :(

Comment: Can I still do it then?

Comment: still not working... in-fact when I'm using **scanf("%[^\n]%*c", (f+i)->name);** It's not event asking for input

Comment: Have you read the posted answer? It's best not use scanf at all, use     `(f+i)->name=(char *)malloc(40*sizeof(char)); fgets((f+i)->name, 40, stdin);`