# Why is the while loop getting repeated twice without letting me scan for the 2nd time, when I enter something different the first time?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

When it asks me to enter a character and I enter say 'b', it executes the last line and then the whole loop again along with the last line without executing the scanf statement in between.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char ch = 'C';

     while( ch != 'A')
        {
            printf("Enter your character\n");
            scanf("%c" ,&ch);
            printf("\nLoop must execute completely\n");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: You are entering `"b\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

> scanf("%c" ,&ch);

**Reason**: After entering some character as an input, you will press enter (newline `\n`),and this newline (`\n`) will be read by `scanf` in the second iteration. `%c` format specifier can read white space characters like space, tab, line feed (newline), and carriage return.

**Solution** : Change  `scanf("%c" ,&ch);`  to `scanf(" %c" ,&ch);`. Adding a trailing space in `scanf` will read any extra white space characters.

Comment: Your solution works, but I do not understand why. Why is adding a space before working? Please explain

Comment: @JoyMajumdar : please read this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: @JoyMajumdar  The extra blank space tells `scanf` to skip white space characters and it will actually skip any number of white space characters before reading and storing a character.