# I have tried to make a simple program in C to count the number of char in a string. But it only counts the first word, if i leave any space it stops

Tags: c, string, count, char

I have tried to make a simple program in C to count the number of char in a string. But it only counts the first word, if i leave any space it stops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str1[100];
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    printf("enter string:\n");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    while (str1[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
        count++;
    }
    printf("total number of char %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: Tip: Investigate what `scanf("%s", ...)` do

Comment: The `%s` `scanf` format specifier will not read an entire line, but only a single word. If you want to read an entire line, I recommend you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", str1)` reads a single word and leaves the separator (any sequence of white space) and the rest of the input line in the `stdin` buffer. If you want to count the number of characters in the full input line, use `fgets()` to read a full line and stop on the newline (`'\n'`) in addition to the end  of string (`'\0'`).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str1[100];
    int i;

    printf("enter string:\n");
    if (fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin)) {
        for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (str[i] == '\n') {
                str[i] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("total number of chars: %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```