# can't input string with space in c structure

Tags: c, struct, gets

I wanted to write a program to generate student mark list. But in this one, i can only insert first part of the name. the rest is skipped. i looked most forums about this problem and it still happens. help if you can.

```
// mark list using struct

#include <stdio.h> #include <string.h>

struct mlist { char name[30]; int cs; int maths; int eng; int total; float perc; };

void main() { int n, i;
printf("How many Students? : ");
scanf("%d", &n);

struct mlist std[n];
struct mlist *ptr = std;

printf("Marks out of 100");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("\n\nEnter details of Student %d ==>\n", i + 1);
    printf("Enter Name : ");
    scanf("%s", ptr->name);
    printf("Enter Computer Science Marks : ");
    scanf("%d", &ptr->cs);
    printf("Enter Mathematics Marks : ");
    scanf("%d", &ptr->maths);
    printf("Enter English Marks : ");
    scanf("%d", &ptr->eng);
    ptr++;
}

ptr = std;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("\n---------------------------------\n");
    printf("Name : %s\n", ptr->name);
    printf("Computer Science : %d\n", ptr->cs);
    printf("Mathematics : %d\n", ptr->maths);
    printf("English : %d\n", ptr->eng);
    ptr->total = ptr->cs + ptr->maths + ptr->eng;
    ptr->perc = (float)ptr->total / 300 * 100;
    printf("Total %d with %.2f%%\n", ptr->total, ptr->perc);
    ptr++;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think a `%s` format means in `scanf()`?

Comment: Read a line at a time with `fgets`. For the name, [remember to remove the newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776). For lines with numbers, use `strtol` or `sscanf` to convert the number.

Comment: @Ameen Aslam, stop using `scanf()` until you know why it is weak.  Look to `fgets()` to read all user input.

Comment: This has nothing to to with your `struct`, but rather with how `scanf()` works. As the other comments already say, using `scanf()` for text input might not be the best option. `scanf()` with `%s` does not really care how long the input is or how big your buffer is and it only gets the input until the next whitespace. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248017/20785822) is a nice example of how you could use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", ...)` reads a word.  Here are some options to read a line instead:

1. `scanf("%42[^\n]", s);` where `s` is an array of characters of 42 characters.  Always include a maximum field width (here 42) when reading strings with `scanf()` and friends.
2. `fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);`.
3. `getline();`. is another option if your struct contains a char pointer opposed to array.  It will then dynamically allocate space for the array.

`fgets()` and `getline()` will include the `'\n'` so you may need to remove it with `s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: `getline(&(char *) { s }, &(size_t) { sizeof s }, stdin);`?  Huh?  [`getline()` requires its pointer to be able to be passed to `realloc()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getline.html):   "If `*lineptr` is a null pointer or if the object pointed to by `*lineptr` is of insufficient size, **an object shall be allocated as if by `malloc()` or the object shall be reallocated as if by `realloc()`**, ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks a lot. I forgot it will reallocate on insufficient space.  Revised answer.  Let  me know if we are not yet good.